# Using Git for website development

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new with using Git on website development and need a suggestion.
I have website example.com (production) and it's clone dev.example.com (development)
Currently I've created 2 git repos for each of them  and can commit and push changes to each of them separately. 
I'm using this solution for each of them:

#### create bare repo

```
cd /home/git/example.com.git
git init --bare
```

#### My config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    worktree = /var/www/example.com/htdocs/
[receive]
    denycurrentbranch = ignore
```

File: hooks/post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh
git checkout -f
```

#### and make it executable

```
chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

#### push files into repo

```
cd /var/www/example.com/htdocs.default
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add example.com git@example.com:example.com.git
git push example.com +master:refs/heads/master
```

and the same for my dev site. So I have 2 different web sites, 2 git repos, and as developer I have to merge all on my laptop and push to git dev repo, then check it in browser and then push it to my production repo and check it on main web site.

Is there a solution to use one git repository (bare?) and have two branches in it: production and development, so I can:

1. clone dev on my laptop
2. then make changes
3. push it to remote dev
4. check in browser that it's ok (when pushing to dev, it should appear
   in  (/var/www/dev.example.com/htdocs)
5. Push the same changes from remote dev to remote production so they'l
   appear in production dir (/var/www/example.com/htdocs)

How to configure git (what configs, commands I need) so it can do so and the main question how to let him know that I'm satisfied with how dev.example.com looks in my browser and he can push/merge/commit this changes from dev to production?
Thanks

Comment: You need to have a deployment process which takes the repository and generates all the necessary files from that. Once you have that, you just need to set up git hooks to trigger the correct deployment when you receive new pushes to a certain branch.

Comment: Like Capistrano/Webistrano? So there is no built in mechanism for this in git? I mean I still have to use 2 different repost for my 2 web sites even is they are almost the same (as dev and production could be).

Comment: No, you don’t need multiple repositories. Just a clean deployment process. And Git doesn’t have this built-in because it is a *version control system* not a Swiss Army knife for every situation it could be used in.